# oracle to postgres migration table type issue

Tags: oracle, postgresql, database-migration

[image]

As shown in the image I'm facing this issue

I'm getting syntax error.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Where in the [Postgres manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) did you find that `TABLE OF` is supported in Postgres?

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL and Oracle are two different relational database systems.

They have different SQL dialects, and the stored procedure languages PL/SQL and PL/pgSQL are somewhat similar, but different when you get to the details.

You probably want to translate

```
TYPE mytype IS TABLE OF mytab.mycol%TYPE;
myvar mytype;
```

to

```
myvar mycoltype[];
```

(assuming that `mytab.mycol` is of type `mycoltype`.)

The syntax will be different, but you can do similar things.

Comment: [`%TYPE` is supported too](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-TYPE) by PL/pgSQL, but unfortunately, the syntax does not allow arrays to be created from such references.